# Regression for Multiple different Groups in SPSS

Tags: regression, correlation, statistical-significance, spss

I have a data set With multiple different people who fill out a survey for multiple days. I have added examples but these are not the real data points we pulled from the survey. I would like to do a correlation or regression test for each subject to see if there is a relationship between individual subject happiness value and the increase and decrease of weight. In SPSS is there a way to do regression analysis for each subject individually then to compare the results of if there is a significant relationship.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a mixed model situation. An example is shown in the Case Studies for SPSS Statistics at [Using Linear Mixed Models to Fit a Random Coefficients Model](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLVMB_26.0.0/statistics_casestudies_project_ddita/spss/tutorials/mixed_diet_intro_03.html). This model fits a common fixed slope and intercept across subjects, as well as random slopes and intercepts for individual subjects to see how they depart from the common values. To show the individual deviations check the box to "Display parameter predictions for this set of random effects" in the Random dialog box.